# How to publish Apache axis2 web service without a web container (Tomcat)?

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, application-server

Is possible make (and execute) a web service using Axis 2 without
a web container (as Tomcat)?
If yes, how can I do that?

Comment: For more clearly. I mean/ I want something like this.... In file: `HelloWorldPublisher.java` has `Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:9999/ws/hello", new HelloWorldImpl());` it works (publish web service) without any application server. ( mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example )

Answer (score 0):

Axis 2 can run standalone. Details are here. [apache axis installation page](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/installationguide.html)

Comment: I mean/ I want something like this....    In file: `HelloWorldPublisher.java` has
`Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:9999/ws/hello", new HelloWorldImpl());`
it works (publish web service) without any application server. ( http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example/ )